# Summing range of fields using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Using ArcPy, how do I sum a range of fields?

While I know this is possible using field calculator, I am looking for something repeatable for long list of fields that changes. I already have code that will determine which fields should be included and gets placed in a list with one additional field that will house the total. This list is the variable `workfields` The idea of what I'm looking for looks something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, workfields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        row[-1] = sum(row[0]:row[-2])
        cursor.updateRow(row) 

del row, cursor
```

Basically row[-1] = sum(row[0],row[-2]) needs to work like:row[-1] = row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + .. row[-3]+row[-2]. I have gotten come code to work that loops through the entire list updating a variable using y += row[i] that can then be passed through as to what row[-1] should be. I think that going this route is a bit clunky and just adds too much time in running the script when I have hundreds of fields I need added up for thousands of records.

Comment: To compute total sum( row[:-2]) Maybe add list before row.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixIP Looks like your comment could easily be worked up into an answer.